# datatype in typescript for a variable who can have one of the value in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, interface, initialization

I want to make interface/any other way for this so that can use that datatype instead of this long string or string pattern.i want to remove this incomplete or submitted pattern and put some small variable there

```
export interface IWithdraw{
  applicationType: "incomplete" | "submitted" | "interview" | "inactive" | "offer" | "preonboard" | "hired",
  jobApplicatonId:number,
  startedOn: Date,
  inProgress:boolean,
  error?:string
}
```

Comment: This is not clear. Where is the array of strings?

Comment: how about `type T = "incomplete" | "submitted" | "interview" | "inactive" | "offer" | "preonboard" | "hired"`
And then using `applicationType: T`